# How do I enable ctrl-c escaping in RStudio's vim editing mode?

Tags: r, vim, rstudio, vim-plugin

RStudio has a nice vim editing mode. However, having to reach all the way to the escape key for escaping is demoralizing. Vim allows you to use ctrl-c to e.g. exit editing mode. Is it possible to enable ctrl-c escaping in RStudio's vim editing mode?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but another option.
You could rebind your otherwise useless Caps Lock key to escape. That way you won't have to reach long, and it's just one button instead of two. Doing this is rather simple. You can also have it function as escape when used alone, but as ctrl when used in combination with another key. That way you won't have to reach as far for ctrl either. On Linux this is done with the program 'xcape', and i believe there is an alternative for Mac. Windows can propably do this with autohotkey. But the simple Caps lock > Esc would propably help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of RStudio are you using, and what platform?

With RStudio v0.99, `Ctrl + C` should exit insert mode; it looks like perhaps this isn't the case on Windows. I'll file a bug for RStudio and hopefully it will be resolved for the next release.

(I am guessing that the issue here is that we have a conflict between Copy (normally `Ctrl + C`) and the 'exit insert mode' behaviour we might normally want when Vim keybindings are enabled.)

Comment: I am using the desktop RStudio 0.99.483 in Ubuntu 14.04. So it works for you? What system are you running?

Comment: Ah, I'm running on OS X -- I guess it needs to be checked all non-OS X platforms, then?